# How to apply a configuration template to multiple project at once in TeamCity?

Tags: build, teamcity, devops, teamcity-9.0

I have 100 TeamCity sub-projects and a configuration template.

I want to add the configuration template to all the 100 projects.

Currently I am adding the template to projects, one after another.

Is there a way to add the configuration template to all the 100 sub-projects at once?

Answer (score 0):

Move the template to the parent project. This must be a project that's above all the 100 sub-projects; in the worst case, this is the .

After that, the template will be visible (and usable) from all the 100 sub-projects.

Answer (score 0):

Using the versionned settings, you can backup your current configuration as xml inside your VCS.

Then, change Versionned settings to use configuration from the VCS inside the `.teamcity` folder.

Using regex/massive replacement, you can edit all of your configuration, and push it to your repository.